# Python Regex pattern Matching

Tags: python, regex

I have a list in the following format:

```
data =['| test_data_14865428_0              |', '| test_data_1486612450_0              |', '| test_template                  |', '|id_1475020800_0              |']
```

I want to fetch all the list elements of the format test_data_* into a new list (tables). The list tables should store the name in the format test_data_*

My try:

```
import re
tables = []
pattern = re.compile("| test_data\S")

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if pattern.match(data[i]):
        tables.append(data[i])

print(list_of_tables)
```

Comment: `[i for i in data if '| test_data_' in i]` or `[i for in test_data if re.search(r'\| test_data\S', i)]`

Comment: print([i for i in test_data if re.search(r'\| test_data\S', i)]) is giving me an empty list

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your data includes the substring `test_data_` you could filter for that static phrase without requiring a regex:

```
data = filter(lambda v: 'test_data_' in v, data)
```

If you then want to filter out the space and pipe separators you could use translate to remove the unwanted characters:

```
data = map(lambda v: v.translate(None, " |"), data)
```

Of course the expressions could be combined into a compound expression.

---

One problem with the regex in the original code above is that the `|` needs to be escaped so it will be treated literally.  Currently it is treated as an alternate operator.

Though perhaps not the most elegant implementation, the following is one option:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("\| *(test_data_[\d_]+)")
def search(val):
    found = pattern.match(val)
    return found and found.group(1)
print(filter(lambda f: f, map(search, data)))
```

The filter with the identity map just removes records that had no match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` to select the values that contain "test_data_", then map a function across those values to clean up the strings. No regex required.

```
import operator

td = map(lambda s: s[2:].split(' ', 1)[0], 
         filter(operator.methodcaller('startswith', '| test_data_'),
                data))
print(list(td))
```